# Is there a way to condense multiple rows of excel data in one row based on index

Tags: excel, vba

Example: The first screenshot shows the fruit eaten by a kid everyday. Is there some function that can collect all the data in the first sheet and output the data as shown in the second screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of the intent]

Comment: Have you tried to use a Pivot table?

Comment: Not sure, but instead of those *circles* if you use the number 1, I think you could do it by [Consolidate data in multiple worksheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get used into Pivot tables. Its the best way to handle such things.
Sry for the German Excel Language. But you should be able to understand the settings by its positions.

[image]